# Why is this simple jQuery toggle not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggleclass

I am wondering why this `toggle` is not working.
The `addClass` method and therefore hiding the `nav` is working well... Is there a simple typo I am missing or am i getting the concept wrong?
Thanks for support.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").addClass("js");

  var $menu = $("#menu"),
    $menulink = $(".menu_link");

  $menulink.click(function() {
    $menulink.toggleClass("active");
    $menu.toggleClass("active");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.menu_link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5rem;
  right: 1.5rem;
  color: black;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.menu_link .active {
  background-color: red;
}
.js nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
}
nav .active {
  max-height: 15rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#menu" class="menu_link">Inhalt</a>
<nav id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Punkt 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Punkt 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Punkt 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Punkt 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in your CSS; the `.active` class is placed directly on the `nav` and `.menu_link` elements so you need to remove the spaces between their selectors:

```
.menu_link.active {
    background-color: red;
}

nav.active {
    max-height: 15rem;
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/edj3pguc/)

Comment: Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

try removing the space before .active. so it becomes

```
.menu_link.active {}
```

And

```
nav.active {}
```